# Loop to copy data from cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy data in a loop.

```vb
    Dim i As Integer, intvaluetofind As String

    intvaluetofind = "Value"
    For i = 1 To 500    
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = intvaluetofind Then
            Cells(i, 5).Formula = "='Data'!C2"
         End If
    Next i
```

When it finds "Value" in **B** it applies the formula. Now, I have three blank spaces before the loop finds "Value" next time, but it applies `"='Data'!C2"` again.

I would like it to apply `Cells(i, 5).Formula = "='Data'!C3"` on the next loop and so on until it runs out of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add another counter variable which increments each time the value is found.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, intvaluetofind As String, j As Long

intvaluetofind = "Value"
j = 2

For i = 1 To 500
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = intvaluetofind Then
        Cells(i, 5).Formula = "='Data'!C" & j
        j = j + 1
     End If
Next i

End Sub
```

However, you could do this with a formula, something along these lines

```
=IF(B1="Value",INDEX(Data!C:C,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,"Value")+1),"")
```

which I haven't tested